# Possible loss of precision

Tags: java

I am trying to run this code in java and getting following error, required int found double.

```
public class UseMath{
public static void main(String[]args){
  int x = Math.pow (2,4);
System.out.println ("2 to the power of 4 is" + x);

 }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Are you sure it's not the other way around? [Oracle says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) that `Math.pow()` takes doubles, you're giving it `ints`

Comment: declare `x` as `double x=...`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29), it says, that `Math.pow()` expects two `doubles`, and returns a `double`. When you pass ints to this function, it means no harm, because casting (converting) an `int` to `double` means no loss. But when you assign the value to an `int`, it means, it can lose precision.

Simply do this:

```
int x = (int)Math.pow(2,4);
```

or

```
double x = Math.pow(2,4);
```

Comment: what if want to round the value and don't mind the precision

Comment: For someone's future reference, we should probably use ceil or floor? @harshakumarReddy